# How to find the projected area in the x-y plane of an ellipsoidal cap rotated by angle $\beta$?

Tags: integration, conic-sections, area, surfaces

[Image of an ellipsoidal cap](https://keisan.casio.com/has10/SpecExec.cgi?path=05000000.Mathematics%252F01000300.Volume%2520and%2520surface%2520area%252F13000700.Volume%2520of%2520an%2520ellipsoidal%2520cap%252Fdefault.xml&charset=utf-8)

I am trying to compute a part of the projected area in the x-y plane (base area) of an ellipsoidal cap rotated in the x-y plane by an angle $\beta$. So I am taking a point on the rotated ellipsoid given by its parametric form:

$$x = (a \cos(\theta) \cos(\beta)-b \sin(\theta) \sin(\beta)) \sin(\phi)$$
$$y = (a \cos(\theta) \sin(\beta)+b \sin(\theta) \cos(\beta)) \sin(\phi)$$
$$z = c \cos(\phi)$$

where the axis size in x coordinate is 'a', the axis size in y-coordinate is 'b' and the axis size in z-coordinate is 'c'. $(\theta)$ is the angle with x axis in x-y plane and $(\phi)$ is the angle with z axis in the spherical coordinates:

Now for full projected area in the x-y plane I double integrate the following from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $0$ to $\phi_0$, where $\phi_0$ is the angle with z-axis at the cap height:

$$A_{xy} = \iint \mid{dA_{xy}}\mid = \iint dx \times dy = \iint f(\theta,\phi) d\theta d\phi $$

I integrate the area over an absolute value of $dA_{xy}$, otherwise I get $0$. Following the steps I differentiate x and y partially over $\theta$ and $\phi$

$$dx = -(a \sin(\theta) \cos(\beta)+b \cos(\theta) \sin(\beta)) \sin(\phi) d\theta + (a \cos(\theta) \cos(\beta)-b \sin(\theta) \sin(\beta)) \cos(\phi) d\phi$$

$$dy = -(a \sin(\theta) \sin(\beta)-b\cos(\theta)\cos(\beta)) \sin(\phi))d\theta +(a \cos(\theta) \sin(\beta)+b\sin(\theta)\cos(\beta))\cos(\phi) d\phi$$

$$dz = -c\sin(\phi)d\phi$$

$$ dA_{xy} = dx*dy = \frac{1}{2}sin(2\phi)(ab\cos(2\theta)cos(2\beta)-(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}sin(2\theta)sin(2\beta))d\theta d\phi$$

After integration my total projected area in the x-y plane changes with the angle $(\beta)$. It should stay constant irrespective of the angle of rotation.Is my approach correct? Or is there an error in my method which I cannot find? Please help.

Comment: If you really want to integrate over $\theta$ and $\phi,$ you need to figure out the area of the infinitesimal region bounded by $d\theta\,d\phi$. That region generally is _not_ a rectangle with edges parallel to the axes, that is, you don't get its area just by multiplying $dx$ and $dy.$

Comment: Did you take into account the change in $\phi_0$?

Comment: Do you mean $\phi$? $\Phi_0$ is a constant.

Comment: @DavidK. In spherical coordinates the bounded region will be $r^2 \sin(\phi) d\theta d\phi$. Do you know what will be the same for an ellipsoid?

Comment: Why are you integrating over $\phi$ at all? Its value is fixed for the horizontal slice/projection, therefore $d\phi=0$. Integrate $\frac12(x\,dy-y\,dx)$, or, if you prefer, $\frac12 r^2\,d\theta$, over the boundary curve. The integrand simplifies quite nicely and you end up with the area of the equatorial ellipse scaled by $\sin^2\phi_0$ as one might expect.

Comment: @amd Thanks a lot. That works. But why $\frac{1}{2}(xdy-ydx)$?

Comment: $\frac12\det\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\dx&dy\end{bmatrix}$, the area of the “infinitesimal” triangle with sides $(x,y)$ and $(dx,dy)$. It approximates the area swept out by the radial vector in the same way that $\frac12r^2d\theta$ does in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing fine up through your calculation of $dx$ and $dy$, but then took a wrong turn when you computed the resulting volume element. I’m not really sure what you did to end up with the expression that you have for what you call $dA_{xy}$, but you can’t just multiply the expressions that you have for $dx$ and $dy$ to compute it. You’re essentially performing a coordinate transformation on $dA$, so you have to use the change-of-coordinate formula $$dx\,dy = \det{\partial(x,y) \over \partial(\phi,\theta)}d\theta\,d\phi,$$ with the Jacobian determinant as the conversion factor. If you work through this correctly, you’ll end up with a somewhat messy expression that involves neither $\theta$ nor $\beta$.

However, there’s a simpler way to perform this area calculation. If you fix $\phi$ and set $z$ to zero, you have a parameterization of the boundary of the projection. This suggests using Green’s theorem to turn $\iint_RdA$ into a single integral over the boundary. There are many antiderivatives of $1$, but experience suggests that the most convenient one for this problem is $\frac12(x\,dy-y\,dx)$. This is the area of the “infinitesimal” triangle with sides $(x,y)$ and $(dx,dy)$ that approximates the area swept out by a radial vector. In this case, the integrand eventually simplifies to $\frac12ab\sin^2\phi_0$, which results in an area of $\pi ab\sin^2\phi_0$ as one would expect.

Comment: Thanks. But if I also want to calculate the projected area of the rotated ellipsoidal cap in the $x-z$ and $y-z$ planes which are segments, I can't take the area of an "infinitesimal triangle". What will be the expression for the projection of the "infinitesimal surface area element" on each 3 coordinate planes? Should I do a coordinate transformation of the projection of the "infinitesimal surface element" in other planes? i.e.
$$dA_{yz} = dydz = det\frac{\partial (y,z)}{\partial (\theta,\phi)}d\theta d\phi$$
$$dA_{xz} = dxdz = det\frac{\partial (x,z)}{\partial (\theta,\phi)}d\theta d\phi$$

Comment: @TanmayaMishra Why not? If a segment of the boundary happens to be parallel to a coordinate axis then one of the terms will vanish, but that’s OK. The bigger problem you’ve got if you’re going to use Green’s theorem is working out the boundary of the projection. Projecting the cap parallel to the “slice” is more complex than the perpendicular projection and deserves a new question.

Comment: I added another question for perpendicular projection in the x-z plane. The boundary of projection can be derived and given in http://quickcalcbasic.com/ellipse%20line%20intersection.pdf
Please find the question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828409/how-to-express-the-polar-angle-coordinates-for-boundaries-of-an-ellipse-maximum

Comment: I have rephrased the question. Please see if you can help.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828409/how-to-find-the-projected-area-in-the-x-z-plane-of-an-ellipsoidal-cap-rotated-by